# Migrating to Confluence - Updating author field and created or modified field in confluence

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

We are planning to migrate content from a custom app (html pages) to confluence. Apart from regular body field, the source system has fields like created by, modified by, created and modified date. We are planning to use Confluence REST API to push the content. How can we update the above fields (created by, created date, etc) in confluence? I understand doing anything directly in database is not supported, but we are open to any options.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know REST API doesn't support updating author and modified date of the page. However, you can migrate your content first and then update pages from database side. Please take a look at their [documents](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-change-the-creator-of-a-page-720830744.html) for further details.